# bootstrap link in thumbnail

Tags: cakephp, hyperlink, thumbnails

I want to display thumbnails as

```
       <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
          <a href="/admin/contacts/index" class="thumbnail">
            <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-5x center-block"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
```

i tried but it is showing html not icon

```
   <?php echo $this->Html->link(
                 '<i class="fa fa-envelope fa-5x center-block"></i>'
                               ),
                  array('controller'=>'contacts','action'=>'index','admin'=>true),
                array('class'=>'thumbnail')) ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the escape attribute

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(
     '<i class="fa fa-envelope fa-5x center-block"></i>',
      array('controller'=>'contacts','action'=>'index','admin'=>true),
      array('escape'=>true,'class'=>'thumbnail')) ?>
```

or the [Html->tag](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3atag) function

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(
      $this->Html->tag('i', '', array('class'=>'fa fa-envelope fa-5x center-block')),
      array('controller'=>'contacts','action'=>'index','admin'=>true),
      array('escape'=>true,'class'=>'thumbnail')) ?>
```

(I'd go with the `Html->tag` function)

Comment: can I make the icon center inside anchor tag, it is shown left aligned

Comment: you can add whatever you want inside the option array, classes, styles... read the docs for more info on that, I left the link there.